# How to check user given password to md5 format password from database in java

Tags: spring, hibernate, hql, md5

I am giving input password in normal string

```
public JobSeeker validateJobSeeker(String um, String pas) {

    System.out.println("in side jobseek valid dao");
    String hql= "select j from JobSeeker j where j.emailid=:u and j.password = COMPRESS(MD5(:pass))";

    List<JobSeeker> listofjobseeker = (List<JobSeeker>) sf.getCurrentSession()
        .createQuery(hql)
        .setParameter("u", um)
        .setParameter("pass", pas).list();
    return  ( listofjobseeker.size() > 0 ) ? listofjobseeker.get(0)  : null;
}
```

O/p = 
List listofjobseeker = null.

This is my table:

```
 select * from jobseeker;

id | confirmpassword  | emailid  | message | password | phoneno| username | usertype  | address_id |
 +----+----------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+-
    |  1 | 8337da1b34a7b4fec56bc0a418ca6e22 | xyz@gmail.com | NULL    | 
 8337da1b34a7b4fec56bc0a418ca6e22 | 123456 | Angad    | jobseeker |          1
```

I want to validate user for login.I converted user given password into md5 pass format and stored into db at user_registration time.When user come to login with same email_id and password .I am not able to check md5 formatted pass to user pass.

Comment: Don't use md5 for password hashing. It was hacked 10 years ago and is considered unsafe. If you insist on not changing it, just use a plain password, this offers about the same security

Comment: i know that ,but it's done with md5.Can u give me solution for this same.

Comment: Pro-tip: on Stack Overflow, readers appreciate carefully written posts using real English words. Please save the txtspk for Facebook `:-)`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can first convert the raw password into a MD5 format before matching it in the database. A method like following should help.

```
private static String encode(String md5){
       try {
            java.security.MessageDigest md = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            byte[] array = md.digest(md5.getBytes());
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
              sb.append(Integer.toHexString((array[i] & 0xFF) | 0x100).substring(1,3));
           }
            return sb.toString();
        } catch (java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        }
        return null;

    }
```

You can change your method as below.

```
public JobSeeker validateJobSeeker(String um, String pas) {
  String encryptedPass = encode(pas);
  ...
  .setParameter("pass", encryptedPass).list();

}
```

Comment: Thanks for solution!!, I did this way its working fine , but i want directly check user pass to dbs pass using hql query .Have any idea.

Comment: what is a database that you are using?

Comment: MySql :  Server version: 5.7.19 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: you can try this sql `SELECT IF ((SELECT confirmpassword FROM JobSeeker WHERE emailid = :u) = MD5(:pass), 'true', 'false') AS valid` in SQLDeveloper. It should work fine.It can then be converted to hql easily

Comment: Thanks Man!! Its done working fine , but i use createSQLQuery instead of hql. , it returning string value we have to validate that string.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for my question. I used SQLQUERY instead of SQL because I don't know HQL syntax to match md5 pass to user pass: To validate user using emaild and normal user pass compare with md5 encrypted pass.

Let's checkout below:

```
String hql =    "SELECT IF ((SELECT password FROM JobSeeker WHERE emailid = :u) = MD5(:pass), 'true', 'false') as r ";

        SQLQuery sql =    (SQLQuery) sf.getCurrentSession()
                                                                 .createSQLQuery(hql)
                                                                   .setParameter("u", um)
                                                                      .setParameter("pass", pas);

         sql.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
         Object validate = sql.uniqueResult();
         Map map = (Map) validate;
         System.out.println("inside sys.out.print is ========= " + map.get("r"));
         String val = (String) map.get("r");
         System.out.println("val is  = " + val);

         if(val.equals("true"))
         {
             List<JobSeeker> jobSeeker = (List<JobSeeker>) sf.getCurrentSession().createQuery("select j from JobSeeker j where j.emailid =:u ")
                                                          .setParameter("u", um).list();
             return (jobSeeker.size() > 0 ) ? jobSeeker.get(0) : null ;
         }
         else{  System.out.println("Invalid User , plz retry :( ");
             return null;
         }

    }
```